# How to properly define getters for class variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

I decided to write small Rails model concern which allows my models to be sluggable.
This concern provides method which can be used to redefine slug column.
Currently it works, but I am not sure if my code does not smell.
First of all I want to know if I can use any shortcut to define getter for class variable.

Probably my code should be refactored. Here it goes:

```
module Sluggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    extend FriendlyId

    slug_with :name

    def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      slug.blank? || sluggable_attribute_changed?
    end

    def sluggable_attribute_changed?
      public_send("#{self.class.sluggable_attribute}_changed?")
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def slug_with(attribute)
      @sluggable_attribute = attribute

      apply_friendly_id(@sluggable_attribute)
    end

    def apply_friendly_id(sluggable_attribute)
      friendly_id sluggable_attribute, use: %w(slugged history)
    end

    def sluggable_attribute
      @sluggable_attribute
    end
  end
end
```

When I use `rubocop`gem I get warnings about `sluggable_attribute` class method with notice that I use should use `attr_reader` for trivial reader methods.

Please advise how I should improve my code to fit Ruby and Rails conventions.

Thank you!

Comment: Accessors can be defined for instance variables, not class variables. I assume you are referring to class instance variables, which you should be using instead of class variables anyway. The normal way to define an accessor for a class instance variable is like this: `class << self; attr_accessor var; end`.  Also, see [cattr_accessor](http://apidock.com/rails/Class/cattr_accessor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are in the context of Rails i recommend you the 'class_attribute' method ([doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-class_attribute)). In my opinion is most appropriate for rails gems.